# Font color not applying

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have the footer font color different( using the selector footer .footer-left ) but the color is getting overwritten by the selector nav ul li a .The specificity of the first selector is 11 and second is 4 . Why is it not working ? I tried !important and inline style too but it did not work .
I thought inline and important will always win . Where am I going wrong ?

HTML :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Google</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
       <header>
            <nav>
                    <ul>
                            <li><a href = "#">Gmail</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Images</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">App</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Signin</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>


        <div id = 'container'>
            <h1 id = 'logo'>Google</h1>
            <form>

            <input type = "text">
            <input type = "submit" value = "Google Search">
            <input type = "submit" value = "I'm Feeling Lucky"> 

            </form>
        </div>

        <footer >     

            <p>India</p>      
            <nav>
                <ul class = "footer-left">
                    <li><a href = "#">Adverstising</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Business</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                </ul>

                 <ul class = "footer-right">  
                    <li><a href = "#">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Use Google.com</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>    
        </footer>


    </body>
    </html>

CSS is :

    * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        box-sizing :border-box;
    }

    body{
        font-family : arial ,san-serif;
        font-size:13px;
    }
    #logo {
        background: url('/img/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') top left no-repeat;
        width:269px;
        height:95px;
        text-indent:-9999px;
        margin : 0 auto;

    }

    #container {
        width: 590px;
        margin :140px auto 30px ;
        text-align:center;

    }

    input[type = "text"]{
        width: 590px; 
        padding : 7px;   
        margin:30px 0 ;
        border : solid 1px #eee;
    }

    input[type = "text"]:hover {   
        border : solid 1px #aaa;   
    }

    input[type="submit"] {
        background: #f2f2f2;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:13px;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        border-radius:2px;
        color:#757575;
        border-radius :2px;
        fvont-weight:bold;

    }
    input[type="submit"]:hover {

        border : solid 1px #aaa;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

     header nav {

        text-align: right;
        margin:25px;
    }

    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding:7px;

    }
      header nav ul li a {
        text-decoration:none;
         color:black;
    }

    footer {

        background:#f2f2f2;
        position : fixed ;
        bottom:0;
        width : 100%;
        font-size:15px;
        color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        margin:60px 0 0 0;
    }

    footer p {

        padding : 5px;
        border-bottom: solid 2px #eee;
        margin:5px;   

    }

    footer .footer-left {
        float : left;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    footer .footer-right {
        float : right;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify which part you want to change color to. If you need the links colored black:

```css
footer a {
  color: black;
}
```

Right now you only specify footer's overall color. And As far I can see, "India" has inherited this, but links are totally different story. You need to specify the color for them or browsers will use their defaults.

Check this example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zeu773zp/

Comment: I have just started learning ...never knew links do not inherit and you need to target them using the a tag . Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Sure thing! Also to keep in mind, it's a good idea to use some kind of framework like Bootstrap. It will make your life much easier and you will be able to do things faster since many things are already done for you. It's quite easy to learn. After that start looking into Sass. 
If you could accept my answer as the one that answered your question, I would immensely appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks,  I just did . I am starting bootstrap next week .

Answer (score 1):

That's not all the css isn't it. Based on the current example my guess this would fix it:

```
footer .footer-left {
  float : left;
  padding: 5px;
  color: red;
}

footer .footer-left a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

I do have to say that your css structure is buildup is kinda of a mess. So maybe it would be a better idea to recode it.

Comment: I know its a mess ..This is my first attempt coding a page ..I am new to this markup and styling thing . I am working to have the css fixed today .Do you have any pointers or further readings for best practices ? I never thought about inheriting the color . Think that is pretty cool .